# Как сделать сдвиг массива вправо для вставки нового элемента?

Tags: массивы, c++

```
//  После каждого четного числа добавить число 0.

const int n=10;
int ar[n*2],k=n,t;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    ar[i]=rand()%10+1;
    cout<<ar[i]<<"\t";
}
cout<<endl<<endl;
for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
    if(ar[i]%2==0){
        k++;// Увеличиваем кол-во
        for(int j=i+1;j<k;j++){  // Пытаюсь сделать сдвиг
            ar[j+1]=ar[j];
        }
        ar[i+1]=0;// Вставка нового элемента    
         i++;  // Обход нового элемента
    }
}
for(int i=0;i<k;i++){
    cout<<ar[i]<<"\t";
}
cout<<endl;
```

Comment: Задачу нужно решать только с помощью сдвига в пределах исходного массива? Дополнительную память нельзя использовать? Может, было бы проще создать временный дополнительный массив?

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что в данном случае проще идти не от начала массива, а от конца. Код наверняка будет проще и более легко отлаживаем.

Ну, или как предложил [[@mikillskegg](/users/751/mikillskegg)](/users/751/mikillskegg), можно использовать еще один временный массив, чтобы не нужно было что-то сдвигать в исходном.

К приведенному же коду навскидку у меня претензий нет. Так в чем собственно вопрос был?

Comment: Сдвигать неполучается,путаются данные. Попробую придумать с дополнительным массивом.

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка вот в чем: 
при сдвиге массива ты записываешь в следующую ячеку значение текущей, а на следующей же итерации это же значение берется как исходное и копируется дальше, получается так:

i = 0 : **1** 2 3 4 5 -> **1** **1** 3 4 5

i = 1 : 1 **1** 3 4 5 -> 1 **1** **1** 4 5

Самый простой вариант - сдвигать с конца (цикл от j = k-1 до >i + 1, arr[j] = arr[j-1])

Comment: до >i Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой и примитивный пример с дополнительным массивом

```
const int ARRSIZE = 10;
int arr[ARRSIZE];
srand (time(NULL));
for (int i = 0; i < ARRSIZE; i++) {
    arr[i] = rand ();
    cout << arr[i] << "  "; 
}
cout << endl;

int newarr [ARRSIZE*2];
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ARRSIZE; i++) {
    newarr[k++] = arr[i];
    if (arr[i] % 2 == 0) newarr[k++] = 0;       
}

for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) 
    cout << newarr[i] << "  ";
cout << endl;
```